# Parsing error: Unexpected token Client Discord.js

Tags: node.js, discord.js

Ok so i have this problem, i am new at node.js, please help, the error says: "Parsing error: Unexpected token Client" i've tried to do something for a while and i don't know what to do.

```
const {Client, Intents} = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"]})

client.login("TOKEN")
client.on('ready', function () {
    
}

Client.on("message", message => { try{
       let server1 = "861068256844316683";
       let server2 = "936852675352481842";
       let channel1 = "861068256844316686";
       let channel2 = "936852675352481845";
       let emojis = [":joy:",":rofl:",":heart_eyes:",":smiling_face_with_3_hearts:",":sunglasses:",":nerd:",":face_with_monocle:",":kissing_heart:",":pensive:",":rage:",":face_with_symbols_over_mouth:",":hot_face:",":cold_face:",":thinking:",":flushed:",":scream:",":yawning_face:",":lying_face:",":heart_eyes_cat:",":joy_cat:",":scream_cat:"];
       let msj = message.content;
       if (msj.includes("@everyone")) return;
       if (msj.includes("@here")) return;
       if (msj.includes("<@&")) return;
       if (msj.includes("http")) return;

       if(message.channel.id === channel1){
         let emoji = emojis[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)];

         if(message.member.id === "947818875137953863") return;
         let chatGlobal = Client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === server2).channels.cache.find(c => c.id === channel2);

         chatGlobal.send(`**${emoji} ${message.member.user.username}:**\n> ${msj.replace("\n","\n> ")}`);
         
       }
  
      if(message.channel.id === channel2){
         let emoji = emojis[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)];

         if(message.member.id === "947818875137953863") return;
         let chatGlobal = Client.guilds.cache.find(g => g.id === server1).channels.cache.find(c => c.id === channel1); 
         
         chatGlobal.send(`**${emoji} ${message.member.user.username}:**\n> ${msj.replace("\n","\n> ")}`);
         
       }
     } catch(error){
       
       console.log(error)
       
     }})
```

Comment: As a side topic, I would strongly recommend hoisting your constants to the module scope instead of being declared in the handler, as well as using a code formatter and a linter. The most popular options are Prettier and ESLint respectively.

Comment: You're missing a closing parenthesis `)` after `client.on('ready', function () {
    
}`

Comment: It doesn't help the problem, is true that i missed it but it doesn't work for the problem

Comment: Are you getting a different error now? If so, your question is answered

Comment: Nop, the same error

Comment: Your code looks valid apart from the of `Client` vs `client`.

Answer (score 0):

The error is coming because you missed a parentheses when you are calling `client.on('ready')`. Also, as @omar al-hamad told, you are confusing the `client` (with a small c) with `Client` which is completely different. Your fixed code might look something like this:

```js
const { Client } = require("discord.js");
const client = new Client({ intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"] });

let server1 = "861068256844316683";
let server2 = "936852675352481842";
let channel1 = "861068256844316686";
let channel2 = "936852675352481845";
let emojis = [
  ":joy:",
  ":rofl:",
  ":heart_eyes:",
  ":smiling_face_with_3_hearts:",
  ":sunglasses:",
  ":nerd:",
  ":face_with_monocle:",
  ":kissing_heart:",
  ":pensive:",
  ":rage:",
  ":face_with_symbols_over_mouth:",
  ":hot_face:",
  ":cold_face:",
  ":thinking:",
  ":flushed:",
  ":scream:",
  ":yawning_face:",
  ":lying_face:",
  ":heart_eyes_cat:",
  ":joy_cat:",
  ":scream_cat:",
];

client.on("ready", function () {
    console.log(`Logged in as ${client.user.tag}!`)
});

client.on("message", (message) => {
  try {
    if (message.author.bot) return
    let msj = message.content;
    if (msj.includes("@everyone")) return;
    if (msj.includes("@here")) return;
    if (msj.includes("<@&")) return;
    if (msj.includes("http")) return;

    if (message.channel.id === channel1) {
      let emoji = emojis[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)];

      if (message.member.id === "947818875137953863") return;
      let chatGlobal = Client.guilds.cache
        .find((g) => g.id === server2)
        .channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === channel2);

      chatGlobal.send(
        `**${emoji} ${message.member.user.username}:**\n> ${msj.replace(
          "\n",
          "\n> "
        )}`
      );
    }

    if (message.channel.id === channel2) {
      let emoji = emojis[Math.floor(Math.random() * 21)];

      if (message.member.id === "947818875137953863") return;
      let chatGlobal = Client.guilds.cache
        .find((g) => g.id === server1)
        .channels.cache.find((c) => c.id === channel1);

      chatGlobal.send(
        `**${emoji} ${message.member.user.username}:**\n> ${msj.replace(
          "\n",
          "\n> "
        )}`
      );
    }
  } catch (error) {
    console.log(error);
  }
});

client.login("TOKEN");
```

(Note: I took the liberty to format the code and put some variables at the top so it can be accessed everywhere.)

Answer (score -2):

you declared client with small letters like this:

```
const client = new Client({intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"]})
```

---------^

and then you are trying to call with with a capital C like this:

```
Client.on
```

instead do:

```
client.on
```

Comment: While you're probably correct it doesn't fix the reported error `Parsing error: Unexpected token Client`

Comment: Ive put the client.on how you explained and now i have other error, the error is: "Identifier "client" has already been declared"

const {client, Intents} = require('discord.js')
const client = new Client({intents: ["GUILD_MESSAGES"]})

client.login("TOKEN")
client.on('ready', function () {
    
}

client.on("message", message => { try{